# WPF Remove MenuItems from TitleBar context menu

Tags: wpf

I was able to add an item using the Window Handler and such, but I also want to remove the already existing items (the window tool window inside of our main app, and we don't want all those options there). In the screenshot below it shows the one I added and the ones I want to remove (pretty much all of them). Let me know if there's a way to do this.

EDIT:

Or better yet, how to put my own context menu with XAML (if possible). But I don't want to lose the title bar or the aero effect.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I am looking to do the same exact thing.  So, I would love to hear your solution if you have one.

Comment: @bsh152s sorry, didn't find a way to do it, we still have all those menu items there.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own ContextMenus in WPF

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Dock" Command="{Binding ...}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </Grid.ContextMenu>

</Grid>
```

Just be careful with the Bindings because WPF ContextMenus are not part of the same Visual Tree as the rest of your controls, so bindings do not work as expected. You will probably need a relative source binding to the `PlacementTarget` to get your command.

Comment: Hi Rachel. Thanks for the suggestion. I already know how to do that. The problem is that I need to do it in the title bar, which makes it a lot trickier. If I do what you suggested, the context menu will be inside the window, but I don't need it there. Thanks =).

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is slightly different than what you are asking, but it may help.  You are wanting to modify the built-in menu from the window title bar... but what if you overlay that menu with your own using custom chrome (like how mozilla firefox/MS Office does it)?

To do this, download WPF Shell Integration Library from http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/WPFShell and play around with it.  The library also includes a few other cool features like jump lists.

more documentation on this technique is at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2008/09/08/custom-window-chrome-in-wpf.aspx