# Remove Title Bar's Context Menu completely in WPF Window

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have created a WPF Window and set its Window Style property to 'None'.
Yet when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Up Key</kbd> combination, a context menu appears on the top left of the Window.

Is there a way to disable that too..

Note: Handling the PreviewKeyDown events does the job but I am looking for a different way.

```
   <Window

    x:Class="WpfApplication14.MainWindow"

    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"

    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"

    WindowStyle="None"

    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

      <Grid/>

    </Window>
```

Comment: Maybe this is useful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897832/wpf-remove-menuitems-from-titlebar-context-menu

Comment: Have you tried: `Resize: NoResize` (not sure what's the Property name.

Comment: @Tico ResizeMode set to NoResize disables minimize and maximize options in the menu, but menu still appears!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4630842/how-can-i-disable-the-default-richtextbox-command-for-ctrl1 - is your answer

Answer (score 7):

Adding the following code in code behind clears the Style of Title bar and blocks the System Menu:

```
    private const int GWL_STYLE = -16; //WPF's Message code for Title Bar's Style 
    private const int WS_SYSMENU = 0x80000; //WPF's Message code for System Menu
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);

    // Handling the Messages in Window's Loaded event

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var hwnd = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
        SetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_SYSMENU);
    }
```

Taken From :
[How to hide close button in WPF window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743906/how-to-hide-close-button-in-wpf-window/958980#958980)

Answer (score 3):

I think you have to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> to show the system menu, not <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> :).

See [this article](https://web.archive.org/web/20140323064931/https://winsharp93.wordpress.com/2009/07/21/wpf-hide-the-window-buttons-minimize-restore-and-close-and-the-icon-of-a-window/), it describes how to remove the system menu of WPF.

Comment: You are right Jerry Alt+Space shows the menu.. Alt then Up key also shows context menu..probably because Alt sets the focus to the invisible Title Bar.

Answer (score 0):

in my case i wanted to keep the icon, but i also landed here, so if you only want to disable the system menu activation (and keep the icon) you could hook the WMProc and supress that. my solution will let the eventhandling untouched.

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        KeyUp += MainWindow_KeyUp;
    }

    protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Log("KeyUp overridde: {0}", e.Key);
        base.OnKeyUp(e);
    }

    private void MainWindow_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        Log("KeyUp event: {0}", e.Key);
    }


    private const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    private const int SC_KEYMENU = 0xF100;
    private const int NO_KEYPRESS = 0;
    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);

        HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        source.AddHook(this.WndProc);
    }

    private void Log(string msg, params object[] args)
    {
        Debugger.Log(0, string.Empty, string.Format(msg, args));
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        // Handle messages...

        if (msg == WM_SYSCOMMAND)
        {
            if (wParam.ToInt32() == SC_KEYMENU)
            {
                int iLParam = lParam.ToInt32();

                Log($"Key: {(char)iLParam} ");

                if (lParam.ToInt32() == NO_KEYPRESS)
                {
                    handled = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
}
```